# SSRS Shared folder subscriptions credentials

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We are creating reports and try to deliver them using a shared folder adding a subscription for that, but when we created it as for user credentials and we can add them for test proposes but the environment on prod, for security reasons we cannot put the credentials on it because IT uses all with windows authentication for security reasons.

Is it any way to set a windows user to deliver the file on the shared folder without add it when is configured?

Comment: can you rephrase that one long sentence please. I can't seem to follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for the database and the database server can be set in the data source as an expression, however you eiteher need to define a "ReportAdmin" user to always publish the reports with. The publisher should know the credentials prior to deployment. Other than that the data source will balk and inform that it needs credentials to run the operations :(